# Why doesn't my markup result in clickable table rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, onclick, link-to, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to create a clickable table row using Rails 6 and Bootstrap 4 (not sure if it's a Bootstrap issue). The rows are not 'clickable' with the following code:

index.erb.html:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">PPU</th>
        <th scope="col">Notes</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @accounts.each do |account| %>
        <tr>
        <% link_to "Show", account_path(account) %>
        <th scope"row"><%= account.name %></th>
        <td><%= account.ppu %></td>
        <td><%= account.notes %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
</thead>
</div>
```

The table renders fine but no DOM click.

**UPDATE** I figured out how to make each attribute in the row clickable like so:

```
<th scope"row"><%= link_to account.name, account_path(account) %></th>
```

Now I want to make the entire row clickable which requires a different approach.

Comment: You need to use JS to make the whole row clickable

Answer (score 1):

The `link_to` method creates an anchor element (not a click handler, as you've implied). Where you've placed it results in invalid HTML. You can't wrap table cells with other elements, so the browser may be stripping it. Hard to say since we don't see the rendered markup.

Put the link inside each cell, wrapping the cell contents. If you actually do want a whole-row click handler you'll need a different approach. In that case you'll need to revise your question to better explain your intent.

Comment: I updated my question. I'd like the whole row to be clickable. Does this require Javascript?